# Why does this formula not work in the referenced worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I am writing a rolling data function for a spreadsheet.  The issue I am having is the formula only works in worksheet it is used in `KPI` and not the one that is referenced `HzTracking`.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(HzTracking!$A$2),MATCH(HzTracking!$A$2,HzTracking!$B$2:$V$2,0)+COLUMN(HzTracking!$A$2))),6,-1,1,-12)
```

- http://www.excelgirl.com/2011/12/example-continued-using-offset-with-indirect-in-building-formulas/
- https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html
- https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/offset.html

Comment: So to be clear - in your worksheet, that formula correctly returns a range.  But you're trying to create a Named Range with that formula and it's not working. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Lets say you have two worksheets, sheet1 and sheet2.  If you use this formula in sheet1 but want the referenced range in sheet2, it will return the range from sheet1.  There are no errors and the correct range is returned but on the wrong sheet.

Comment: Where in the formula do you account for the second sheet? Is that name in a cell somewhere?

Comment: I reference the second sheets cells "HzTracking!$A$2".  Maybe this isn't enough?

Comment: I think you need `INDIRECT()` around that too.  I see you have `OFFSET(INDIRECT(...` but also when you *need* the sheet reference, use `INDIRECT(HzTracking!$A$2)` I think that may work.

Comment: This does not seem to be working; `#REF` error.  I agree that the issue is with `INDIRECT`.  Do you know of an alternative? `OFFSET(ADDRESS(...` returns an error as well

Comment: Ah I know the issue! `INDIRECT` converts the text string provided by `ADDRESS` into a reference.  This reference does not contain the worksheet `HzTracking!...`.  Lol now we just need a work around.... @BruceWayne